# Sudden change in terminal prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

I use macOS Catalina. I was adding R kernel to Jupyter notebook. After the download completed, my prompt text changed to `@x86_64-apple-darwin13`. When I check the hostname from System Preferences, it is normal(not changed).

What could have possible happened during download? I do not think this is a malware, but could it be so? And, how can I change my prompt name back? To change, I used `sudo scutil --set HostName [hostname]`, but it didn't work. Probably, it is not just the hostname, something else is going on.

```
> echo $HOST
kikibobo
> echo $PS1
(base) %n@%m %1~ %# 
> print -lr -- "${(qqqq)PS1}" "${(qqqq)PROMPT}"
$'(base) %n@%m %1~ %# '
$'(base) %n@%m %1~ %# '
```

Note: I am not sure if it is related but, I see a blurred question mark on my home directory folder which is visible on terminal top bar. When I right click on the folder icon, folder path is `x86_64-apple-darwin13/Users/`.

Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of running these commands in a terminal: `hostname`, `echo $HOST`, `cat /etc/hostname`.

Comment: Please post the output of `print -lr -- "${(qqqq)PS1}" "${(qqqq)PROMPT}"`. Had you customized your prompt or were you using the system default?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I just unset LSCOLORS. Could that be related? I strongly believe that adding R kernel to Jupyter does something, but I have don't understand how that happened.

Comment: @kikibobo "I see a blurred question mark on my home directory folder which is visible on terminal top bar": Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75751/why-does-the-folder-icon-in-my-terminal-have-a-question-mark-overlaid